# Specification mandate value for attribute Response

Tags: java, xml

I wrote an API which is working on the back-end but I can't get to generate the xml response, I am trying this:-

```
    response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter writer=response.getWriter();
    writer.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    writer.append("<TestInsert Response>");
    writer.append("<Firstname>"+fName+"</Firstname>");
    writer.append("<Lastname>"+lName+"</Lastname>");
    writer.append("</TestInsert Response>");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

`response` is of type `HttpServletResponse`.

Why I am getting the error when I hit the url on browser?

Comment: what is the error you're getting ?

Comment: Specification mandate value for attribute Response

Answer (score 2):

You XML is not well-formed

```
<TestInsert Response>...
```

The browser wants an attribute value, e.g.

```
<TestInsert Response="">...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped

Comment: @SohamBanerjee also note that `</TestInsert Response>` should be `</TestInsert>`